# Which is correct? brrr v brr v brrrrr

Tags: ambiguity

I have come across brrr and brr - which is someone indicating that they are cold.
So which spelling is correct?
Or can you be REALLY cold - BRRRRRR! Interjections! Aha!

Comment: There's no real accepted spelling. It's not considered a 'word'. But both 'brr' and 'brrr' are used in print. Search for it and see which instances you like better. Extra r's beyond three is even more informal.

Answer (score 3):

Collins Dictionary has:

> ***[brrr](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/brrr)***
> in British English

> informal -
> an exclamation used to suggest shivering.

but other dictionaries suggest “brr”. I think there is no “correct” spelling and the more “r” you use the colder you feel.